# Differentiation in MATLAB with GUI

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a GUI app in MATLAB that takes in an expression from a text box (edit1) and then prints the derivative of that expression in a static text (text2). Here's what I've tried:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(~, ~, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
equation = get(handles.edit1, 'String');
y = eval(equation);
derive_func = diff(y, 'x');
set(handles.text2, 'String', derive_func);
```

Is there something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to symbolicly differentiate the user input string with respect to the variable symbolic variable 'x'. However, in the context of your callback function, no symbolic variable x is defined. For me (using the newly released MATLAB R2014a and Symbolic Math Toolbox), adding the line

```
syms('x')
```

at the beginning (assuming that the equation string contains something like 'x^2') of the callback function and converting 'derive_func' into a chararcter array (using char) before calling the set function makes the code work.

Check the [online doc of MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/syms.html) to get more detailed info on symbolic expressions.

Comment: I still can't seem to make it work. I added 
    syms('x')
at the beginning of the code but when I click the button during runtime I still get that bell sound (in Windows 7)